# Elementarily equivalence

Tags: logic, model-theory

> Suppose we have two equivalence relations $A$, $B$ s. t. $|A|=|B|$ (equipotent sets).
>
> Is $A$ elementarily equivalent to $B$, $A \equiv B$?
>
> My definition of elementarily equivalent is the following: $A \equiv B$ iff $Th(A)=Th(B)$.

I've tried to use the definition taking an arbitrary sentence $\varphi$ in the lexicon $\mathcal{L}$ s. t. $A \models \varphi$ or $B \models \varphi$ , also, I tried to go through equivalence classes, but I don't even know how to proceed.

I would appreciate some hint/answer, Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Reveillark "Equivalence relation" is often used as a shorthand for "set equipped with an equivalence relation" in this context - e.g. a structure whose language is a single binary relation symbol, in which that symbol is interpreted as an equivalence relation.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think that if they partition the domain into a different number of equivalence classes, then they are not elementarily equivalent (say, one partitions it into two, whereas the other partitions it into three).

Comment: @mum, is Spanish your mother-tongue?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately, the problem does not even say in which lexicon $\mathcal{L}$ are we working, so I'm asuming first order language and $A, B$ two arbitrary equivalence relations with same cardinal. @Cheesecake Yes :)

Comment: (: you don't have to put `¿` in English. (:

Comment: @Cheesecake Thanks for the edit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two equivalence relations with the same finite number of classes, they'll be elementarily equivalent if and only if for each possible size of class (an element of $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$, we don't distinguish infinite cardinals) they have the same number of classes with that size.

e.g say $A$ has two classes, one with 2 elements, the other with infinitely many elements. Say $B$ has two classes, one with 3 elements, the other with infinitely many elements. Then $A$ and $B$ are not elementary equivalent since the formula $\varphi := \exists x \exists y \ \Big(x \neq y \wedge \forall z\ \ (xEz \to (z = y \vee z = x)\big)\Big)$ holds in $A$, but not in $B$.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense! Well, I get it but, ¿How should I start the proof that $A$ elementarily equivalent to $B$ in that case?

Comment: @múm With a back and forth, it is relatively easy.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, by $|A|$ and $|B|$ you mean the cardinal of the relations themselves, not the set they're defined in, right?

(Edit: Thanks to Alex and OP comments, so it's rather cardinality of underlying set, which is the same as the cardinality of an equivalence relation on it if the set is infinite as Alex showed)

As Nagase said in comments, there's no elementary equivalence if the relations partition the set in a different (finite) numbers of classes.

For example, define on $\mathbb N$ the following equivalence relations: $A=\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ and $B=((2\mathbb N)\times(2\mathbb N))\cup((2\mathbb N+1)\times(2\mathbb N+1))$, i.e, $xBy$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same parity iff $x-y$ is even.

Both $A$ and $B$ are countable, but you have $A\models\forall x\forall y\, x\mathcal Ry $ (namely, there's only one equivalence class) and $B\not\models \forall x\forall y\, x\mathcal Ry$ because $(0,1)\notin B$ (in fact $B$ has two equivalence classes).

Comment: I'm sure that $|A|$ means the cardinality of the structure $(A,E)$, i.e. the cardinality of its underlying set $A$, not the cardinality of the relation $E\subseteq A^2$. But note that for an equivalence relation on an infinite set $A$, these are the same! Since $E\subseteq A^2$, $|E| \leq |A|^2 = |A|$. And since $E$ is reflexive, $|A| \leq |E|$. So by Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein, $|E| = |A|$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Scientifica. We are asumming that $|A|$ means the cardinality of the set $A$, as Alex pointed out. There's a lot of sense in the relations between the numbers of classes as you said, Thank you!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh thanks for your comment! Never noticed that $|E|=|A|$ for equivalence relations on infinite sets :D

Comment: @múm No problem. As Alex said, it's the same. Anyway, the relations $A$ and $B$ are both defined on the same set $\mathbb N$.